# Is the Unitarian Universalist Association really creedless?

Tags: unitarianism, universalism

My understanding is that the Unitarian Universalist Association has no creed, but its name suggests otherwise.
As a Unitarian church, are its members expected to deny the Trinity or Jesus' status as the Son of God?
The second label, "Universalist," suggests a belief that everybody will eventually go to heaven. Does this imply an expectation that members profess belief in an afterlife?

Comment: The 'Unitarian' in the name is probably anachronistic or a vestige of earlier organizational belief, as they seem to accept people from all sorts of religious backgrounds, including atheists.

Answer (score 5):

I have been Trinitarian all my life. The below is for information purposes. The content below is in the public domain. Bold highlights are added for clarity.

---

The website of the UUA states definitively :-

> Our beliefs are diverse and inclusive. **We have no shared creed.**

[Beliefs and Principles](https://www.uua.org/beliefs/what-we-believe)

> Most Unitarian Universalist Christians believe in God, but **not the traditional God-as-Trinity** that most Christian churches promote.

[Beliefs and Principles](https://www.uua.org/beliefs/what-we-believe)

> Many of us live with the assumption that **life does not continue after death,** and many of us hold it as an open question, wondering if our minds will have any awareness when we are no longer living. **Few of us believe in divine judgment after death.**

[Life and Death](https://www.uua.org/beliefs/what-we-believe/life-death)

> a growing number of Unitarian Universalists weave strands of **Islam** into their faith today.

[Belief and Principles](https://www.uua.org/beliefs/what-we-believe)

> Some of us practice indigenous religions and **Modern Paganism.**

[Belief and Principles](https://www.uua.org/beliefs/what-we-believe)

> I think Jesus did die and **decompose** in the grave like every other human being who has died before, and since. (Andrew James Brown)

[UUWorld](https://www.uuworld.org/articles/though-jesus-did-not-rise-dead?_gl=1%2A1im1116%2A_ga%2ANTc5NzkxNDg5LjE2ODA0NjMzNzg.%2A_ga_CN7F7RET4F%2AMTY4MDQ2MzM3Ny4xLjEuMTY4MDQ2NDA3MS4wLjAuMA..)

Comment: Thank you. I have read this site before, but my question has more to do with the fact that the words "Unitarian" and "Universalist" imply a creed. Also, I have found nothing online about Trinitarian Unitarians.

Comment: 'Trinitarian Unitarian' would be a contradiction in terms. My own impression is that some parties designate themselves by religious terminology but in practice their words indicate that what unites them together into a body - is a rejection of Trinitarian doctrine, not a shared acceptance of a creed of their own.

Comment: @NigelJ Since UUs accept all sorts of religious beliefs, I am guessing they would accept a Trinitarian, and that the title 'Unitarian' is anachronistic.